# Convergence in Probability of functions defined in metric spaces

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(S,d)$ a metric space, $\xi$ and the sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ be $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(S)$-measurable maps.

According to Wikipedia we require that $(S,d)$ be separable to define convergence of $\xi_n\rightarrow\xi$ in probability but other texts (such as Kallenberg) don't mention separability, so is it needed to ensure that $\forall\epsilon>0,\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[d(\xi,\xi_n)\geq\epsilon]=0$ is well-defined?

Secondly it is claimed that convergence in probability is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[d(\xi,\xi_n)\wedge1]=0$ and $\rho_1(X,Y):=\mathbb{E}[d(X,Y)\wedge1]$ defines a metric on the set $\mathcal{M}$, of all $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(S)$-measurable maps. I am a bit stuck here and not sure how to show that the two definitions of convergence are equivalent, I tried using the Markov equality but don't get anywhere.

It is also claimed the $\rho_2(X,Y):=\inf\{\epsilon>0:\mathbb{P}[d(X,Y)>\epsilon]\leq\epsilon\}$ defines a metric on $\mathcal{M}$ and so do to me it seems quite obvious that $\rho_2(\xi,\xi_n)\rightarrow 0$ is equivalent to convergence in probability as the only difference is the $\geq$ sign, so am I right are is there a more detailed argument?

And so $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ must be equivalent metrics as the have the same convergent sequences?

So any help with any of my questions is really needed and appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, why wouldn't it be well defined?

For the secon question, note that $\mathbb{E}[min(d(\chi,\chi_{n}),1)] \leq \mathbb{P}(d(\chi_{n},\chi)\geq \epsilon) + \epsilon $

Comment: Yes, exactly and my question why is it that some texts require $(S,d)$ to be separable as I don't see why it is needed to talk about convergence. Thanks

Comment: Or is it that as Polish spaces are ubiquitous in probability so most metric spaces are assumed to be Polish even though it may not be needed?