# Convergence in probability in metric spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, measurable-functions, separable-spaces

Let $X,X_1,X_2\dots$ be random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and taking values in a metric space $(S,d)$. We write $X_n\overset{p}{\to}X$ if $P[d(X_n,X)\geq \epsilon]\to 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

**Question:** Do we need $S$ to be separable for this to make sense?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition_2) indicates yes, but this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2179127/522332) indicates no. The definition on page 27 of Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures* puts no restriction on $S$, but the definition on page 287 of Dudley's *Real Analysis and Probability* imposes separability.

The distance function $d:S\times S\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with respect to the product topology on $S\times S$, and so is $\mathcal{B}(S\times S)$ measurable. On the other hand if $X,X_n:\Omega\to S$ are both Borel measurable, then the product map $(X,X_n):\Omega\to S\times S$ is $\mathcal B(S)\otimes \mathcal B(S)$ measurable. So it seems we need separability to ensure $\mathcal{B}(S\times S)=\mathcal B(S)\otimes \mathcal B(S)$ so that the composition $d(X_n,X)$ is measurable.

However if $X=c$  a constant, then I believe this restriction is not needed.

Is this correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if the metric space is not separable, you can still defined convergence in measure as $X_n$ converges in measure to $X$ if $P^*\big(d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon\big)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, where $P^*$is the outer measure associated with $P$ or the Daniell mean if $\mathbb{1}_{\{d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon\}}$ associated to $P$. When $(S,d)$ is separable then the set $\{d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon\}$ is measurable and its $P^*$ outer measure (or Daniell mean) is just $P(d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. So we really need separability for measurability of $d(X_n,X)$, although if $X$ is constant then this not necessary right?